# How to conditionally run a build agent job with a pipeline variable?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps pipelines there's an option to conditionally run a *task* based on a pipeline variable. This is handled under the *Run this task* > *Custom conditions* field and it uses the syntax:

```
eq(variables['VarName'], 'Desired Value')
```

An *agent job* has a similar field for conditional execution under *Run this job* > *Custom condition using variable expressions*.

However, when I use the same syntax as a conditional task the result always evaluates to *'false'*.

So how can I conditionally run an *agent job*?

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs/screenshots? I just tried on my build and the condition works.

Comment: works for me too. may be your variable is not updated properly. please check your variable is updated correctly

Comment: I have my first agent job set the variable. Inside that same job I conditionally run tasks based on that variable. In the next job I try to run the entire job conditionally based on that variable but it always equates to false. However, I can conditionally run individual tasks in that job based on the same variable. So I know the variable get sets correctly. I copy/pasted the same conditional logic to the agent job - but it doesn't work.
I'll dig up some logs in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer. Unfortunately, it is not possible to conditionally run an agent job with a variable that is modified during build execution.

[From the Azure DevOps Pipeline documentation under Pipeline Variables:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=designer%2Cbatch#set-in-script)

> To define or modify a variable from a script, use the task.setvariable
>   logging command. **Note that the updated variable value is scoped to
>   the job being executed, and *does not flow across jobs or stages*.**

Comment: I don't think this is completely correct - see the section "Set a multi-job output variable" in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?tabs=yaml%2Cbatch&view=azure-devops#set-in-script).

Comment: I'll fix the confusing grammer oddity in my answer but I think what I want is still not possible. In that link it says "This does not update the environment variables, but it does make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same job." And that's the problem - I'd like to have a variable that is editable across agent jobs.

Comment: That's in the "Set a job-scoped variable from a script" subsection; there's another subsection called ["Set a multi-job output variable"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?tabs=yaml%2Cbatch&view=azure-devops#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) right below that that shows how to do what you want (but you have to use YAML rather than the designer to achieve it).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this worked for me:

```
- job: Job1
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      if (some condition)
      {
          Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=RunJob2;isOutput=true]True")
      }

    name: ScriptStep
- job: Job2
  dependsOn: Create_Build_Matrix
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Job1.outputs['ScriptStep.RunJob2'], 'True'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/

This one gives you to pass variables from one stage/job to another stage/job in the **same release pipeline**. I tried and it's working fine.

Also to run this you need to give some permissions for release pipeline. To allow for updating the Release Definition during the Release you need to configure the Release Permission Manage releases for the Project Collection Build Service.